# SQL Dump upload to phpmyadmin

Tags: command-line, phpmyadmin, cmd, mysql

I have a dump of [Ontonotes](http://www.bbn.com/ontonotes/)-[v3.0](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/docs/LDC2009T24/OntoNotes-Release-3.0.pdf) in sql format, of size 2.33 GB. I am trying to upload it on phpmyadmin on windows XP. Via GUI its not allowing me as the size exceeds the max file size allowed. Therefore, I followed the trick mentioned on [this website](http://www.ryantetek.com/2011/09/importing-large-sql-files-through-command-line-when-using-phpmyadminxampp/)

It worked at the start and data started to be uploaded at phpmyadmin server. But when the size  of database on server reached 1.5 GB, it stopped uploading i.e. neither there is any improvement in upload as seen on server nor the terminal command is suspending.

I tried to find this size limit in php.ini file but couldn't find it. Any suggestions on how to do it.

Comment: Are you using a hosted mysql server ? some times there are limits on the size of the files you can create

Comment: @ManseUK I am using xampp and the server is my local server

Comment: Thanks all. I left it overnight and the next day, the whole .sql file was updated in database. I still don't know precisely why it stopped in between. Any comments on why this happened are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try command line:

```
C:\mysql_path\bin\mysql.exe --user=xx --password=xx --host=localhost --port=3306 --database=xx < C:\yourdata.sql
```

Comment: This is indeed what is mentioned on the website. I didn't required the port though.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for:

```
upload_max_filesize
```

and

```
post_max_size
```

in your php.ini, you can edit the file size upload from there. You can also do it alernatively via the .htaccess file if you use one.

Comment: This is for the upload via GUI. Right?

Answer (score 0):

why not use bigdump.php

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Comment: How exactly does it works? does it breaks them into small dumps and then imports them?

Comment: First of all, upload your dump using ftp program.  Then modify the bigdump.php to suit your needs (database login info, utf etc).  Basically it will read the file in streaming mode and execute query.  Simple!

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini file the configuration values you're searching for are:

```
upload_max_filesize
```

and

```
post_max_size.
```

But why not use the mysql console instead:

mysql -uroot -pSuperSecretPass db_name < bigSQLdumpfile.sql

If you don't have the file on the server you could always do a "scp" or "wget" (This assumes that you are on a Linux box.).